# CS0012 error when connecting to azure key vault with a ClientSecretCredential in a SSIS script task

Tags: c#, ssis, azure-keyvault

This is my code in the script task void Main

```
var kvUri = "myKVURL";

ClientSecretCredential c = new ClientSecretCredential("MyTenant", "MyClientID", "MySecret");

var newUri = new Uri(kvUri);

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), c);

var secret = client.GetSecret("TestSecret").Value.Value;

Dts.Variables["User::KeyValue"].Value = secret;

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

This is my error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0012  The type 'Uri' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. ST_89eda56bbb4740abaa476abc76bad3cb C:\My\Dir\AppData\Local\Temp\1\Vsta\SSIS_ST150\Vsta__RsLsgToVEOM75__vUnStuQ\VstahfjzFXySnU__iQAt126nx4Q\ScriptMain.cs   101 Active

I have installed the nuget packages for Azure.Identity and Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets and their dependancies to the GAC and I have added a referenced to them in the project. If I follow the same process in a c# console app the code runs just fine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The fact that the error references "netstandard 2.0" leads me to believe your console app is based on ...whatever we call the non-Framework version of .net code. You have correctly attempted to install nuget packages to the GAC so that you can use them in an SSIS Script Task/Component but make sure the .NET version/architecture is also in sync

Comment: hi @billinkc I am not sure why it is erroring on the URI statement. This isnt part of the Azure packages or dependencies. If i remove the ClientSecret code i can output info from the URI library to a variable in SSIS without any issues.